# Як назвати продукт "сканування"?

Tags: переклад, значення-слів, словотворення, віддієслівні-іменники

Що ми отримуємо при *скануванні*? Скан?

Comment: Скан, відбиток, сканований продукт

Answer (score 4):

#### Словники

> [Scanning](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scanning) - present participle of scan.

тобто

> [Scan](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scan) - to look at something carefully, with the eyes or with a
>   machine, in order to get information.

знаходимо

> [ЗНЯТТЯ́](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F) - Дія за знач. зня́ти і зня́тися.
>
> [ЗНІМА́ТИ](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) - Точно відтворюючи, копіюючи, переносити на щось
>   розміри, форму і т. ін. чого-небудь.
>
> [ЗНІ́МОК](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA) - Зображення кого-, чого-небудь, одержане способом
>   фотографування, рентгену і т. ін.

#### Я теж маю слово

Якщо дослідите глибше, то зрозумієте, що **to scan** означає отримувати інформацію про певний об'єкт, або ж дослідження, огляд об'єкта для отримання інформації для подальшого використання. В нашому випадку найвлучніше слово - це знімати, зняття, знімок.

#### Як назвати продукт “сканування”?

Через прочитане вважаю слово сканування зайвим в нашому словнику. Адже легко можна замінити його декількома варіантами зі схожим значенням зі словника. Тому зміню запитання на таке: Як назвати продукт знімання? А на це запитання вже простіше відповісти: **знімок**.

#### Що ми отримуємо при скануванні? Скан?

Цікаво, як запитання змінює думку. Адже це два різних про одне й те ж саме з різних точок зору.

На основі вище описаного та з розумінням сучасного погляду на значення слова образ виходить, що після зняття інформації ми отримуємо образ знятого. І цей образ зберігаємо у вигляді знімку для можливого подальшого використання. Можливо для створення копії, а може для подальшої обробки і отримання іншого якогось результату.

Answer (score 3):

У словниках слова *скан* я наразі не бачу.

Але оте *-скан-* інтуїтивно інтерпретується як основа слів *сканер*, *скан-код*, *сканограма*, *сканувати*, тому визнання слова *скан* мені здається **лише питанням часу**. 
**Де-факто воно вже вживається**, наприклад, [106 траплянь у корпусі «ГРАК»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac7&queryselector=lemmarow&lemma=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD).

Якщо Вам ж потрібні лише загальновизнані слова, то скористайтеся [порадою Yola](/a/6147).

Також існує термін *сканограма*. І деякі джерела навіть тлумачать його як [зображення, отримане в результаті сканування](https://ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru/164499/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0). Однак на практиці, мені здається, у значенні простого результату сканування воно буде витіснене словом *скан* і залишиться лише в історичному контексті й для [творів специфічного жанру](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D1%8F).

Answer (score 2):

- Один з виходів *[чоботарювання](http://sum.in.ua/s/chobotarjuvannja)* - *чоботи*.
- Один з виходів *[банкування](http://sum.in.ua/s/bankuvaty)* - здача *банку*.
- Один з виходів *[склярування](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F)* - *скло*.

Виходить, що одним з виходів *сканування* може бути *скан* як специфічне *зображення*, бо фактично результат сканування - це *зображення*.

Answer (score 0):

При скануванні у нас виходить скан-копія документи, так як вихідний файл сохроняется на комп'ютері або в пам'яті сканера (як колись), і виходить що це являється копією. А так як вона відсканована, тоді це скан-копія. Можете глянути пару таких словосполучень на https://kstech.com.ua/computeru/top-5-krashchyh-wi-fi-routeriv-2020/ Там якраз використовується слово скан-копія.

Comment: _Скан-копія_ — це справді хороший варіант ([вікісловник](//uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/скан-копія), [ГРАК](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?queryselector=lemmarow&lemma=скан-?копія), [Google Книги](//www.google.com/search?lr=lang_uk&tbm=bks&q=скан-копія)). Але щось [я не бачу](//www.google.com/search?q=скан-копія+site:kstech.com.ua), щоб він використовувався за Вашим посиланням. Будь ласка, замініть посилання на таке, де справді використовуються слово _скан-копія_ (тоді особисто я поставлю плюса), а інакше це схоже на спробу просування сайту kstech.